# How do I call a template within a template?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I've got the following value in an XML file:

```
<document>
  <effectiveTime value="20131008"/>
  <item>
    <effectiveTime>
      <low value=20131008"/>
    </effectiveTime>
  </item>
</document>
```

I have the following as part of my xsl file:

```
<xsl:variable name="today">
    <xsl:call-template name="formatDate">
        <xsl:with-param name="date" select ="/Document/effectiveTime/@value" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- template for date formatting from xml document -->
<xsl:template name="formatDate">
    <xsl:param name="date" />
    <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring($date, 1, 4)" />
    <xsl:variable name="month" select="number(substring($date, 5, 2))" />
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring($date, 7, 2)" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($month, '/', $day, '/', $year)" />
</xsl:template>

<!-- template for comparing against the date of visit -->
<xsl:template name="compareToday">
    <xsl:param name="date"/>
    <xsl:if test="$date = $today">
            <xsl:text>true</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I need to compare the /document/item/effectivetime/low/@value to the value I have stored in the variable $today so that I can make a line in the output (html) be bold format. This is what I have currently to do the compare:

```
<xsl:variable name="IsToday">
    <xsl:call-template name="compareToday">
        <xsl:with-param name="date" select="/document/item/effectiveTime/low/@value"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
<span>
    <xsl:if test="$IsToday = 'true'">
        <xsl:attribute name="style">
            <xsl:text>font-weight:bold;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="/document/item/effectiveTime/low/@value" />
</span>
```

This doesn't work because it's trying to compare 20131008 against 10/08/2013. I can't seem to get the format to be done first before doing the compare. Most (but not all) of the dates in my document are in the YYYYMMDD format.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized what I needed to do. I have to make a variable with the current date first that is formatted correctly. Then pass that variable name to the compare.

```
<xsl:variable name="itemDate">
    <xsl:call-template name="formatDate">
        <xsl:with-param name="date"  select="/document/item/effectiveTime/low/@value"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="IsToday">
    <xsl:call-template name="compareToday">
        <xsl:with-param name="date" select="$itemDate"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

This allows me to compare apples to apples in terms of formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Try following adjustment

```
<xsl:variable name="IsToday">
    <!-- Store formated date in temporary variable -->
    <xsl:variable name="tmp">
        <xsl:call-template name="formatDate">
            <xsl:with-param name="date" select="/document/item/effectiveTime/low/@value"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:call-template name="compareToday">
        <!-- Pass temporary variable into compare template -->
        <xsl:with-param name="date" select="$tmp"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

Or you could nest calling of another named template into xsl:with-param element like

```
<xsl:variable name="IsToday">
    <xsl:call-template name="compareToday">
        <xsl:with-param name="date">
            <!-- Another named template call nested in xsl:with-param -->
            <xsl:call-template name="formatDate">
                <xsl:with-param name="date" select="/document/item/effectiveTime/low/@value"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: that's what I did. I just didn't nest it within the first $IsToday variable

Comment: oh, you're right... I didn't reload page before posting so I missed you have answered it yet.

Comment: Not a problem as soon as I submitted the question, the way to fix it hit me so I went ahead and answered it so as not to leave it open. Thanks for the input though. Does it matter if the temp date variable is nested inside our outside of the $IsToday?

Comment: I think it is only about scope of that variable... the result is the same. I just tried you could also neste calling of another named template into xsl:with-param element (I extended my answer with this possibility).